# UnintentionalCodeFirstException thrown by mstest

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, mstest

I have a test project which references another project, which in turn references a third project containing my Entity Framework 5.0 file (edmx). I find that I can run database-driven unit tests directly from Visual Studio, but when I run from mstest I get the following errors:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException:
>   Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model
>   First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode.
>   To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is specified in the config file of
>   executing application.

I have non-database connecting unit tests which run fine. I've fiddled with my various app.config EF connection strings and they seem to be OK (every tests runs fine on Visual Studio). The problem is when I run mstest from a command line on my desktop or on a build server. This is the command I use:

> MSTest.exe /nologo /searchpathroot:"\Binaries"
>   /resultsfileroot:"\TestResults"
>   /testcontainer:"\Binaries\driver.orderedtest"
>   /testcontainer:"\Binaries\EF.DataAccess.dll"
>   /publish:"http://"
>   /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/99" /teamproject:"ProjectName"
>   /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"Debug" /noisolation /detail:errormessage
>   /detail:errorstacktrace /detail:stderr

I have references to all dll's in the test project, as outlined here: [Entity Framework custom tool does not correctly embed or load the model as resource files](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/345025/entity-framework-custom-tool-does-not-correctly-embed-or-load-the-model-as-resource-files)

I've been on this for a few days off and on, and it looks to me that this is an EF 5.0 bug, but according to the connect link this should be fixed, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: One problem seems to be the /noisolation switch. I removed it and found my tests run on my desktop, but now the tests hang on the build server. I'm wondering if the switches in my MSTest.exe command are incorrect?

Comment: This problem is because I was using TFS 2010 to build a .Net 4.5 solution. I should have been using TFS 2012. Leaving this here for anybody else encountering the same issue. So, recommendation is to make sure you are using the correct TFS version for your .Net version.